# Having trouble parsing and spacing date/fixnum objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I'm building a small app that takes things entered into an input field and displays them directly below that input field when entered.

My goal with this code is to separate those entries by date so that all things posted on June 1 are posted with one line break between them and the first entry of June 2 has 2 spaces between it and the entries from June 1.

This is my code and it's not acting as planned but I can't figure out why, I think it stems from line 3 and something I'm doing incorrectly. (Note: I'm aware this doesn't account for changes in month or year yet. I'll get to that once I figure out proper date spacing)

```
<% for i in (0..(@allLessons.count-1)) %>

<b><%= @date[i].created_at.strftime('%b %d')%></b><br/>

<% if @date[i].created_at.strftime('%d') == @date[i-1].created_at.strftime('%d') %>

<%= @date[i].created_at.strftime('%d') %> <br />

<% else %>

<%= @date[i].created_at.strftime('%d') %><br /><br />

<% end %>           
<% end %>
```

From the controller:

```
@allLessons = Lesson.all
@date = Lesson.find(:all, :order => 'created_at ASC')
```

Any help you could lend on this would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks and iterators are where it's at.

```
@allLessons = Lesson.order('created_at ASC')
@dates = @allLessons.group_by { |lesson| lesson.created_at.beginning_of_day }.sort

<% @dates.each do |date, lessons| %>
  <% lessons.each do |lesson| %>
    <b><%= lesson.created_at.strftime("%d") %></b><br />
  <% end %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

**Annotated**

First we get all of the lessons together. This is equivilant to find(:all, :order => 'created_at ASC'), but I like this newer, compact syntax

```
@allLessons = Lesson.order('created_at ASC')
```

Then we group them all together into a hash where the key is the date and the value is an array of records that were created on that day. `beginning_of_day` converts a `DateTime` into a `Date` where the time is set to `00:00:00`. So, `2012-05-25 18:00` becomes `2012-05-25 00:00:00`. This is so we can group the dates themselves without the time getting in the way

```
@dates = @allLessons.group_by { |lesson| lesson.created_at.beginning_of_day }.sort
```

`@dates` is now a hash where the keys are dates and the values are arrays of lessons from that date. for example, `{ '2012-05-24 00:00:00' => [ lesson_1 ], 2012-05-25 00:00:00' => [ lesson_2, lesson_3 ]`

We then pass the hash into a block, where the key is the date, and the value is the array of lessons. This is saying, for each date...

```
<% @dates.each do |date, lessons| %>
```

Give me the lessons that belong to that date. And for each of those...

```
  <% lessons.each do |lesson| %>
```

print out the date of the lesson

```
    <b><%= lesson.created_at.strftime("%d") %></b><br />
  <% end %>
```

before moving on to the next date, print a `<br />`

```
  <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new-ish to Ruby so I'm still learning blocks. Can you explain how exactly you're figuring out where and how to separate them by day? Is it in the `@dates = @allLessons` line? I'm still a tad confused on how this code works

Comment: Sure! I'm going to edit the post, so just give me a few minutes.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm going to study the crap out of these. Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: That was a phenomenal explanation, @xnm. Thank you so much! I really appreciate you taking all of that time to explain this. Like I said, I'm really going to study and understand this and use it to kick loads of ass in the future!